# how to print to windows network printer using PHP?

Tags: php

I have a label printer that comes with a windows printer driver. I print direct to the printer on port 9100 and some of the labels do not print.  Manufacturer says the preferred way is to print to the windows driver.  How to print to a windows printer using PHP?

ran this code

```
$handle = printer_open('\\\\localhost\\Brother HL-L2370DW series'); 
printer_set_option($handle, PRINTER_MODE, "RAW");
printer_write($handle, "TEXT To print");
printer_close($handle);
```

get error:

```
 Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function printer_open() in C:\xampp\htdocs\srichter\tester\print-network-printer.php:4
```

I have the latest PHP installed on XAMPP on windows desktop PC. Is printer_open no longer supported in PHP?

How to print to a network connected printer?

kind of an answer.  use shell_exec and run the Out-Printer powershell cmdlet:

```
shell_exec( 'powershell "Get-Content -Path /users/srich/steve.txt | Out-Printer -Name \"Brother HL-L2370DW series\""')
```

Comment: As the documentation clearly states that PECL extension is _not_ part of php but needs to be installed separately, as an extension: https://php.uz/manual/en/printer.installation.php On a normal Linux system you could simply click it in the software management. Since you apparently are on MS-Windows this is more complex: you need to identify the right version you need, locate some download page you trust, manually download and install it, depending on the type of installation package you find.

Comment: hoping for something easy.  maybe a shell_exec that runs a powershell script?

Comment: the shell_exec approach actually works:
shell_exec( 'powershell "Get-Content -Path /users/srich/steve.txt | Out-Printer -Name \"Brother HL-L2370DW series\""')

Answer (score 0):

using `shell_exec` worked for me.

shell_exec runs `DOS` `COPY` command to copy file to printer:

```
$errmsg = shell_exec( 'COPY "C:\\Users\\srich\\Dropbox\\notes\\Walker\\' . 
    'Daily notes\\2021\\2021-07-12 GTIN label.zpl" ' . 
    '"\\\\HPLAPTOP\\ZDesigner ZD620-203dpi ZPL"  2>&1' ) ;
echo '<hr>' ;
echo $errmsg ;
```

shell_exec runs `powershell` `Out-Printer` cmdlet:

```
  $errmsg = shell_exec( 'powershell "Get-Content -Path /c/users/srich/steve.txt ' . 
  ' | Out-Printer -Name \"Brother HL-L2370DW series\"" 2>&1 ');
  echo '<hr>' ;
  echo $errmsg ;
```